# Does selenium webdriver support css contains?

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver, contains

I've read that "the css2 `contains` function is not in css3, however selenium supports the superset of css 1,2 and 3."

Will `contains` be supported by Selenium Server using webDriver or it only supported when using the Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across some more information that may be useful to you. To use contains in css selector. You will have to use :contains pseudo class however this is not properly supported in recent versions of CSS selector engines,upon which WebDriver relies for CSS selector, hence it is not a preferred way these days. To get the same effect of using a contains use 
`div[name*='part']` in CSS Selector and will match all div tags where id contains 'part'. This is equivalent to using `//div[contains(@name,'part')]` in XPath selector.

This question has similar discussions as your own.

[Check this stackexchange answer for more information.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/362/a-way-to-match-on-text-using-css-locators)

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it incorrectly implies that the lack of support for the `:contains` pseudoselector is somehow a defect in Selenium. In fact, the pseudoselector is not supported in any level of the CSS selector standard. Since WebDriver relies on the browsers' internal CSS selector engines, the standard is the only document on which one can rely to determine what is supported.

Comment: Getting the div name is not the same as getting the text contents of the WebElement.